# justify content space evenly not showing the sub div to the center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a parent container inside two sub containers are there each container have a fixed height and width in each sub containers i have a loader loader gif.

```css
.parent-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    border: 7px solid black
}

.sub-container-one{
 width:400px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 3px solid blue;
}

.sub-container-two{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.loader{
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.second-loader{
  margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="sub-container-one">
   <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container-two">
    <div class="loader second-loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can is show the  same loader in both sub div at the center , i have added one more class, right now loader is showing not to the center.

when i have given

```
justify-content: center
```

it works , but how can i align the loader to the center of the both div making

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

Also for IE will this work ?

Comment: what about :`.parent-container>div{

    background-image: url("http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}` ? or set the gif within the code and center it via margin:auto https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajzyNX

Answer (score 0):

It Worked. Made the css for the loader as below, removed the position and made width to 100%

```
.loader{
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```